# Registering more AmazonS3Client with configurations on Autofac

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, autofac

I added `AWSSDK.S3` to my project because I want to use `S3FileInfo` to access files on S3 in a clean way, and I registered an instance of the `AmazonS3Client` on Autofac to get it in my services.

Something like this for the registration on Autofac:

```
builder.Register(context => {
    var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("accessKeyId", "SecretAccessKey");
    var config = new AmazonS3Config {
        RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("regionEndpoint")
    };
    return new AmazonS3Client(credentials, config);
}).As<IAmazonS3>().SingleInstance();
```

The point is that if I want to add more configurations to access different buckets on different accounts like this I cannot.
What's the cleanest way to register on Autofac more instances of `IAmazonS3` with different configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is many way to do what you want. It depends on where you get your credentials.

If you have know the credentials when autofac is building you can use named instance

```
    builder.Register(context => {
        var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("accessKeyId1", "SecretAccessKey1");
        var config = new AmazonS3Config {
            RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("regionEndpoint")
        };
        return new AmazonS3Client(credentials, config);
    }).Named<IAmazonS3>("client1").SingleInstance();

    builder.Register(context => {
        var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("accessKeyId2", "SecretAccessKey2");
        var config = new AmazonS3Config {
            RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("regionEndpoint")
        };
        return new AmazonS3Client(credentials, config);
    }).Named<IAmazonS3>("client2").SingleInstance();
```

To resolve them you can use `IIndex<String, IAmazonS3>` or use the `WithParameter` method at registration or an autofac module.

More information on Named instances are available on the documentation : [Named and Keyed services](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html)

If you have the credentials at runtime you can resolve a factory. let's say `ServiceX` needs a `IAmazonS3Client` instance you can have a dependency on `Func<BasicAwsCredentials, AmazonS3Config, IAmazonS3Client>` and *Autofac* will do the magic for you.

```
public class ServiceX 
{
    public ServiceX(Func<BasicAwsCredentials, AmazonS3Config, IAmazonS3Client> factory)
    {
        this._amazonS3Factory = factory; 
    }
    private readonly Func<BasicAwsCredentials, AmazonS3Config, IAmazonS3Client> _amazonS3Factory; 

    public void Do()
    {
        IAmazonS3Client client = this._amazonS3FActory(credentials, config); 
        // do something with client
    }
}
```

Comment: Merci Cyril, by bad I didn't know named services. I like the first approach but I didn't understand how to get my services injecting them in the constructors, should I use the ServiceLocator? In this application I see that rarely the `System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver` so I cannot use the `ResolveNamed` of the Autofac container. Mmm... I miss something.

Comment: I got it, I need to use `ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IAmazonS3>("client1")` adding a reference to `Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation` where needed. I guess this is the right answer even if I don't love it because I need to use in more places a string name and the service locator which is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @MauroPiccotti I editedmy post. You should avoid service locator there is lot of option to get the client you want : `IIndex<TKey, TService>` custom parameter when registering, autofac module, attribute, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not finding an answer that fits, after thinking a bit about it I decided to follow this approach, probably not very clean but it works:

```
public interface IAmazonS3FirstConfig : IAmazonS3
{
}

public class AmazonS3ClientFirstConfig : AmazonS3Client, IAmazonS3FirstConfig
{
    public AmazonS3ClientFirstConfig(BasicAWSCredentials credentials, AmazonS3Config config)
        : base(credentials, config)
    {
    }
}
```

Using the ad-hoc class and interface to register this configuration, and another couple for the second configuration.